# Cannot update member variable inside for loop of method in c++ class

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to create a python like generator with c++ class which will provide the divisors of a number.
Here is the class:

```cpp
using ull = unsigned long long int;
class Divisors {
  public:
  ull x;
  vector<ull> divs;
  ull i;
  bool end;
  Divisors(const ull &x) : x(x), i(2), end(false) {
  }
  ull next() {
    for(; i*i<=x;i++) {
      if(x%i == 0) {
        divs.emplace_back(i);
        if(!((i+1)*(i+1)<x+1))
          end = true;
        return i;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
};
```

The main function is here:

```cpp
int main() {
  Divisors divs(10);
  int cnt = 0; // Just for safety if while loop goes infinite
  while(!divs.end && cnt < 100) {
    auto div = divs.next();
    cout << div << endl;
    cnt++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But the problem is, it is always printing 2. That means the value `i` is not updating in the for loop. Also as `i` is not incrementing, the while goes infinite and stopped by `cnt`.

Comment: Also, I have tried putting `this->i` instead of `i` but didn't work

Comment: *"That means the value i is not updating in the for loop"* - Yup. The value of `i` will *never* update if you hit that `return i;` on the *first* iteration of the loop. That will leave the loop, leave the function, and `i` will remain exactly what it was on entry. If you try running your program in a *debugger* you'll see that is what is happening.

Comment: Unrelated: You may find modern C++'s [Fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (gleefully stolen from C because why not use good ideas?) shorter than the likes of `unsigned long long int` while remaining Standard and thus immediately recognizable to a C++ programmer.

Answer (score 0):

In your post you are writing about **divisor**s. I fear that you mean (prime) factors. This, because you start with 2 and try go until the square root of the numerator.

But, divisors are different. The divisors for 10 are: 1, 2, 5, 10 with 1 and 10 being the trivial divisor.

Your programming style looks like "competetive-programming"-Style. I hope, that it is not, because you will never learn C++ coding in these challenges.

In your `for`-loop, you always `return i` before the `i++` of the `for` will happen. It will exactly run one time, for the value 2. And then return. Next time the same. And so on and so on.

You have additional logical erros. You should refactor your code.

You may have a look on the below example, to get an idea, of how such thing could be implemented. Please note, this code will never work on any competetive challenge. It should just give you some hints . . .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Whatever integral data type
using MyType = unsigned long long int;

// CLass for calculartin divisors incrementally
struct Divisors {

    // Here we store the originally given numerator
    MyType numerator{};

    // Persistent copy of the test value
    MyType testValue{ 1 };

    // And here we will stor all divisors
    std::vector<MyType> allDivisors{};

    // Constructor. Set all values to start
    Divisors(MyType number) : numerator(number), testValue(1), allDivisors{} {}

    // And a similar function to reset the class, in case we want to use it for an additional computation
    void reset(MyType number) { numerator = number; testValue = 1; allDivisors.clear(); }

    // Function, that will get the next divisor
    MyType nextDivisor() {

        // Here we will stor the result of the function. If we cannot 
        // find a result any longer, then0 ist returned
        MyType result{};

        // We run the loop until we have have found some divisor
        bool found{ false };

        // Or until we are at the end
        while (!found && testValue <= numerator) {

            // Check if this value is a divisor
            if ((numerator % testValue) == 0) {

                // Yes, it is a divisor. Set flag to terminate the loop
                found = true;

                // Set the return value, so, the devisor
                result = testValue;

                // And store the divisor in our vector for later use
                allDivisors.push_back(testValue);
            }
            // Continue with next test value
            ++testValue;
        }
        // A valid divisor or 0, if no new divisors can be found
        return result;  
    }
};

// Some test code
int main() {

    // We want to incrementally create divisors
    Divisors divisors(100ULL);

    // Call the next function for the divisor, until everything is found
    for (MyType d = divisors.nextDivisor(); d; d = divisors.nextDivisor())

        std::cout << d << '\n'; // Show one divisor in each loop run

    return 0;
}
```